# How come output for below program is 25?

Tags: java

I tried a lot in interpreting the below program but couldn't come to an point.

```
class Example{
static int a = 9;
public static  void main(String...args) {
    System.out.println(a + 3 + 3 * m1() + a* m1() + 1 + a);
}
static int m1(){
    return (a =2);
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to group by order of operations, and consider that `a` is a static field; so once it's updated, it's going to remain updated (as 2) until something else modifies it:

```
9 + 3 + (3 * 2) + (2 * 2) + 1 + 2  
12 + 6 + 4 + 3  
18 + 7  
25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see operator precedence order [here](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

When you execute your program it will start operation from left to right. when call  `m1()`, you assign `a=2` and return this value. so after a = 2 your equation like:

```
9 + 3 + 3 * 2 + 2 * 2 + 1 + 2
9 + 3 + 6 + 4 + 1 + 2
25
```